# What is the format of donuts in a polygon shapefile

Tags: shapefile, polygon-creation

I am able to create shapefile sets and understand the format(s) of the various files.
I know that if I create a polygon with a hole in it then the hole needs to be a) part of the surrounding polygon and b) have the vertices tabulated in a CCW order as opposed to the exterior polygon that has CW order of vertices.
My question is if I create another interior polygon inside the other one, which way do the vertices need to be written, CW or CCW again.
I do not have ArcGis, I create the shapefiles from other data programatically.
I can find articles on the donuts or holes but not the format of the vertices.
So, If I have a land mass area and I create a hole, say a lake and then an island in the lake, which way is the island coded?
I have QGis 3.18 but there doesn't seem to be a way to create a hole.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 3):

You must model your geometry as MultiPolygon. Both outer rings are CW and the hole is CCW.

[image]

Geometry as WKT is

```
MULTIPOLYGON ((( 6 3, 7 3, 7 2, 6 2, 6 3 )), (( 4 5, 9 5, 9 0, 4 0, 4 5 ), ( 5 4, 5 1, 8 1, 8 4, 5 4 )))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that the vertices of the outer hull have to be set clockwise and vertices for the inner holes (donuts) have to be set counterclockwise. As far as I remember this is a topological rule for ArcGIS but it is advised for other GIS as well, including QGIS.

However, I have vectorized a lot in recent years, and so far ignoring this rule (by mistake or on purpose) from time to time did never create any problems, whereas other topological errors (self intersections etc.) crash certain tools almost every time.

I would try to follow the above rule as good as possible.

To create a donut in QGIS you have to activate the *Advanced digitizing Toolbar* (either click on *View > Toolbars* or right click in the toolbar area and select the right toolbar). There you will find tools for adding donuts etc.

Edit: I just saw, that they moved the menu for activating toolbars and panels in QGIS 3.18. It is now under *Settings* instead of *View* in your *Menu bar*.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I will try it out. The data I am creating must follow Esri's rules, the application wants holes to be CCW to recognize them as such.
I want to be able to edit the shaps and maybe merge them if required. I've had some success with Qgis but AutoCad / LibraCad is much easier. Writing the shapefiles to dxf is easy but translating them back after editing is more complicated.

Comment: If you have to follow ESRI's topological rules, you will have to vectorize holes CCW. Merging should not be a problem in QGIS. Usually importing and exporting from and to dxf is not a problem but this is a different toppic.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. My original question was about subsequent holes or rather non-holes. When you have land data and then a hole for a lake, that is straightforward but what about the island in the lake, is that still CCW?
I've created the land and lake hole and they seem to work but now the shapefile won't load into Global Mapper 5 for some reason. It loads into a later version but the information is not available, the same in ArcView?